# Need to run function before render component

Tags: reactjs

```
const Productabout = () => {


const params = useParams();
const [singleProduct, setsingleProduct] = useState()
const host = "http://localhost:5000"


useEffect(() => {
    if (params.id) {
        getproduct()
    }
}, [params.id])

console.log(singleProduct.name);
```

getting error like Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: No, you need to deal with the fact that the process is asynchronous and the component will initially be rendered _before_ the value is available.

Answer (score 4):

This is practically a situtation where a **loading element** should be rendered first, until your **asynchronous** `getProduct` function fetches the product from the API and sets your `singleProduct` state to it.

Here is a very simplified version of how you could implement that. Many other implementations can be done:

1. Set a default value for `singleProduct`. In this case, I'm setting it to **undefined**.

   ```
   const [singleProduct, setsingleProduct] = useState(undefined);
   ```
2. Now, we can check for the value of `singleProduct`. If it's `undefined`, that means that the `getProduct` function did not finish executing yet and that we should display a loading element instead. When it's finished executing, the value of `singleProduct` would change from `undefined` to some object like `{ "name": "hello world" }`. In that case we can safely display the product:

   ```
   return singleProduct ? <p>{singleProduct.name}</p> : <p>loading...</p>;
   // The code above is equivalent to:
   if (singleProduct)
   {
       return <p>{singleProduct.name}</p>;
   }
   else
   {
       return <p>loading...</p>;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

At the first render, the `singleProduct` is set to `undefined`.

```
const [singleProduct, setsingleProduct] = useState()
```

So when the `console.log(singleProduct.name)` is called during the initial rendering, it will raise an error because it's attempting to access the  `name` property of undefined `singleProduct`.

If you want to monitor the `singleProduct` state, simply use a `useEffect` block where you can log the `name` of `singleProduct` while it's available.

```
const Productabout = () => {
  ...
  const params = useParams();
  const [singleProduct, setsingleProduct] = useState()
  const host = "http://localhost:5000"
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (params.id) {
      getproduct()
    }
  }, [params.id])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (singleProduct) {
      console.log(singleProduct.name)
    }
  }, [singleProduct])
  ...

}
```

Or, if you are too lazy to use `useEffect`, you can simply use something like this:

```
const Productabout = () => {
  ...
  const params = useParams();
  const [singleProduct, setsingleProduct] = useState()
  const host = "http://localhost:5000"
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (params.id) {
      getproduct()
    }
  }, [params.id])

  console.log(singleProduct && singleProduct.name || undefined);
  ...

}
```

or you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?.) if you are using ECMAScript 2020 (ES11).

```
  console.log(singleProduct?.name)
```